# Send Emails at Specific Dates & Times

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have cells containing Date (B2:B10) and Time (C2:C10).

I want to send email based on date & time in cells.

It shows automation error

```vb
Sub Send_Deferred_Mail_From_Excel()
    Dim OutlookApp As Object
    Dim OutlookMail As Object
    Dim cell As Range
    Set cell = Range("B2:C2")

    Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutlookMail = OutlookApp.CreateItem(0)

    'Send Email Using Excel VBA Macro Code
    With OutlookMail
        .To = "gaelvin@gmail.com"
        .CC = "nickjames@gmail.com"
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Happy New Year"
        .Body = "Greeting Gael, Wish You a Very Happy New Year"
        
        'Send email on specific date & time
        .DeferredDeliveryTime = Range("B2:C2")
        
        .Display 'or just put .Send to directly send the mail instead of display
    End With

    Set OutlookMail = Nothing
    Set OutlookApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DeferredDeliveryTime` accepts a `date` as a value, so you need to combine the date and time that you have into a single value.

Due to the way dates work in VBA, you can simply add them together and it should work:

```
.DeferredDeliveryTime = Range("B2") + Range("C2")
```

I would also suggest to add some checks that those ranges contain valid time and dates if you have the chance.